# Not able to send TCP Packets through multi-hop using my protocol

Tags: tcp, ns2

I have implemented a protocol named TRLR for wireless networks which is not an ad-hoc routing protocol. It just allows nodes to send R_UPDATE message after some specified time. Everything is running smooth but TCP source only communicates with the TCPSINK when they are in each other's range. I want to send these packets through multi-hop by the shortest route possible. How to do it in ns-2.34?

Please help.

forward function of my protocol.

```
void
TRLR::forward(RouteEntry* rt, Packet *p, double delay)
{
struct hdr_cmn *ch = HDR_CMN(p);
struct hdr_ip *ih = HDR_IP(p);

if(ih->ttl_ == 0) {

#ifdef DEBUG
fprintf(stderr, "%s: calling drop()\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
#endif // DEBUG

drop(p, DROP_RTR_TTL);
return;
}

if (ch->ptype() != PT_TRLR && ch->direction() == hdr_cmn::UP &&
((u_int32_t)ih->daddr() == IP_BROADCAST)
    || (ih->daddr() == here_.addr_)) {
dmux_->recv(p,0);
return;
}

if (rt) {
assert(rt->rt_flags == RTF_UP);
rt->rt_expire = CURRENT_TIME + ACTIVE_ROUTE_TIMEOUT;
ch->next_hop_ = rt->rt_nexthop;
ch->addr_type() = NS_AF_INET;
ch->direction() = hdr_cmn::DOWN;       //important: change the packet's direction
}

else { // if it is a broadcast packet
assert(ih->daddr() == (nsaddr_t) IP_BROADCAST);
ch->addr_type() = NS_AF_NONE;
ch->direction() = hdr_cmn::DOWN;       //important: change the packet's direction
}

if (ih->daddr() == (nsaddr_t) IP_BROADCAST) {
// If it is a broadcast packet
if (ch->ptype() != PT_TRLR) {
 Scheduler::instance().schedule(target_, p, 0.);  
}
}
else { // Not a broadcast packet 
if(delay > 0.0) {
 Scheduler::instance().schedule(target_, p, delay);
}
else {
// Not a broadcast packet, no delay, send immediately
 Scheduler::instance().schedule(target_, p, 0.);
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: You kind of forgot to describe the problem. What goes wrong when they're not in each other's range?

Comment: Welll, in that case they do not communicate at all.

Comment: That's not a very helpful description. How far do they get? What's the first thing that doesn't happen?

Comment: Sir I don't know which function does TCP use to forward the packets to the destination. When source node sends tcp packet to next node, the next node does not forward the packet it just drops it or something.

Comment: TCP doesn't forward the packets to the destination, IP does that. But you're trying to explain the cause of the problem. I'm asking you to describe it. What *precisely* goes wrong? Does some function get some error? If so, what function? And what error?

Comment: Sir I am still developing my code by understanding AODV code. I am confused about the mechanism ns2 uses when it has to forward tcp packets. AODV uses sequence numbers to find the route to the destination. Error is in the forward function. I have edited my post please check.